# Make perl look ahead for sub prototypes

Tags: perl, function-prototypes

Perl is a bit too forgiving: If you pass extra arguments to `sub`s they are simply ignored.

To avoid this I would like to use prototypes to make sure each `sub` is given the correct amount of arguments.

This works OK as long as I declare the prototype before using it:

```
sub mysub($);
sub mysub2($);

mysub(8);
mysub(8,2); # Complain here                                                            

sub mysub($) {
    mysub2($@);
}

sub mysub2($) {
    if($_[0] == 1) {
        mysub(2);
    }
    print $@;
}
```

But I really hate splitting this up. I would much rather that Perl read the full file to see if there are declarations further down. So I would like to  write something like:

```
use prototypes_further_down; # This does not work

mysub(8);
mysub(8,2); # Complain here                                                            

sub mysub($) {
    mysub2($@);
}

sub mysub2($) {
    if($_[0] == 1) {
        mysub(2);
    }
    print $@;
}
```

Can I somehow ask Perl to do that?

Comment: Fundamentally, what you ask is impossible. Protototyes don't add arguments checks; prototypes change parsing rules for the sub calls. There are must therefore be known before the sub calls are made.

Comment: Why do you put your sub decls at the bottom in the first place? It's just inviting scope leak. So both the reason you ask and to prevent the subs from capturing vars they shouldn't, put your subs before your code.

Comment: You could also use [`PPI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI) to preprocess the source file, extract sub prototypes and put them into a separate file, for example, that you later can `require` at the top of your source file. See this [module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Examine::Subs) for more inspiration.

Comment: @ikegami The example shows one example where you cannot put the declarations first: mysub calls mysub2 which calls mysub.

Comment: So what? Use a forward declaration in those extremely rare cases.

Comment: If you want (some resemblance of) parameter checking, switch to using "proper" subroutine signatures. These die (at runtime) when a subroutine is called with an invalid number of parameters. https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html

Comment: In case you are not aware of it, since v5.20 there are [subroutine signatures](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Signatures), with this precise purpose. There is an in depth discussion [in Effective Perler](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/04/use-v5-20-subroutine-signatures/). They are experimental, and if that kills the deal then I think you're left with manual checking, in the design spirit of Perl. There are modules to aid the checking (but for me they _add_ work). Prototypes are just not meant for what you want.

Comment: You can always get forward compatibility with the subroutine signatures by using (my module) [Filter::signatures](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filter::signatures), but it's a source filter with all the caveats that entails. On the upside, it's a source filter for source code you control so you can adapt your code to it.

Answer (score 4):

> To avoid this I would like to use prototypes to make sure each `sub` is given the correct amount of arguments.

No, you would not.  Despite the similarity in name, Perl prototypes *are not* your father's function prototypes.  Quoting [The Problem with Prototypes](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/08/the-problem-with-prototypes.html) (emphasis mine),

> Perl 5's prototypes serve two purposes. First, they're hints to the parser to change the way it parses subroutines and their arguments. Second, they change the way Perl 5 handles arguments to those subroutines when it executes them. **A common novice mistake is to assume that they serve the same language purpose as subroutine signatures in other languages. This is not true.**

In addition to them not having the same intended purpose, bypassing prototypes is trivial, so they provide no actual protection against someone who deliberately wishes to call your code in (what you believe to be) the "wrong" way.  As [`perldoc perlsub`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) tells us,

> The function declaration must be visible at compile time. The prototype affects only interpretation of new-style calls to the function, where new-style is defined as not using the `&` character. In other words, if you call it like a built-in function, then it behaves like a built-in function. If you call it like an old-fashioned subroutine, then it behaves like an old-fashioned subroutine. It naturally falls out from this rule that prototypes have no influence on subroutine references like `\&foo` or on indirect subroutine calls like `&{$subref}` or `$subref->()`.
>
> Method calls are not influenced by prototypes either, because the function to be called is indeterminate at compile time, since the exact code called depends on inheritance.

Even if you could get it to complain about `mysub(8,2)`, `&mysub(8,2)` or `$subref = \&mysub; $subref->(8,2)` or (if `mysub` were an object method inside `package MyModule`) `$o = MyModule->new; $o->mysub(8,2)` would work without complaint.

If you want to validate how your subs are called using core Perl (prior to 5.20), then you need to perform the validation yourself within the body of the sub.  Perl 5.20 and newer have a ("experimental" at the time of this writing) [Signatures](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Signatures) extension to sub declarations which may work for your purposes, but I've never used it myself, so I can't speak to its effectiveness or limitations.  There are also many [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/) modules available for handling this sort of thing, which you can find by doing searches for things like "signature" or "prototype".

Regardless of your chosen approach, you will not be able to get compile-time errors about incorrect function signatures unless you define those signatures before they are used.  In cases such as your example, where two subs mutually call each other, this can be accomplished by using a forward declaration to establish its signature in advance:

```
sub mysub($foo);                               # Forward declaration
sub mysub2 { mysub(8) }
sub mysub  { mysub2('infinite loops ftw!') }   # Complete version of the code
```

Comment: The experimental subroutine signatures do indeed do argument count checking. [Function::Parameters](https://metacpan.org/pod/Function::Parameters) is a similar extension that's usable on Perl 5.14+ and additionally can perform Type::Tiny type checking.